# how to resize elements in interface builder?

Tags: xcode, interface, resize, builder

I was working my project with XCOde and interface builder, but the little dots around the elements  in interface builder are not showing up anymore. I am not able to resize anything. I created a second xib file and they show up on that one, how is that possible ? I feel that i'm stuck now and that i have to create a new project... or is it a settings that "hides" the bounding boxes of all elements in a xib ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I just recreated the project, it seems that it was a damaged XIB file .  Next time i'll do backups of my whole project every now and then ( i guess i should have used a SVN )